# FreeBSD no internet

Tags: freebsd

I downloaded and installed FreeBSD 10.2 on to an Oracle VM.
First thing I am trying to run pkg, it gives me an error with:

```
No address record
A pre-built version of pkg could not be found for your system.
```

[image]

Then I try to ping google, it gives me an error with:

```
Host name lookup failure
```

[image]

I am new to FreeBSD, not sure if internet is automatically hooked up? Or what do I need to do to make internet working?

P.S. do I need to do any manual configurations with `/etc/rc.conf` and `/etc/resolv.conf`? Those two files don't exist in my `/etc` folder at the moment.

**UPDATE:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the oracle VM set to have internet access? Network adapter is set to available? Connected? And what setting (bridged / NAT / no network)?. Result of your ifconfig (to see if you get any IP address)

Comment: Darius, it is by default on NAT. assume VM will just work. please see update pic

Comment: `em0` is down and has no address(es) assigned so of course network access fails. Did you delete things from `/etc`? I'm not sure about `resolv.conf` but I thought there wasn't any way to install without creating at least a minimal `/etc/rc.conf` -- and that is where `ifconfig_em0=(whatever)` should be, although I think (not recently tested) you can get install to miss that *line*. There's no point in tweaking config on a NAT interface, so try `ifconfig em0 up; dhclient em0` and see what you get.

Comment: M A G I C ! T H A N K S     D a v e !

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Doesn't it qualify as an answer instead of a comment?